# Ich werde der Polizei sagen, sie soll/sollen

Tags: pronoun

Welches Pronomen ist hier zu verwenden?

> Ich werde der Polizei sagen, sie *soll/sollen* dich verhaften, und wenn sie es nicht *tut/tun*, dann lasse ich dich selbst ins Gefängnis werfen.

Comment: Was und mit welcher Begründung denkst du selbst, was richtig ist?

Comment: -1 wegen "This question does not show any research effort" Siehe auch: https://german.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Both variants are okay. This is because German isn't too strict on the plural of collectives as *die Polizei*. It may be seen as the **collective** of police staff, hence singular, or it may be seen as an **assembly** of police staff, hence plural.

Actually, this strict distinction between collective and assembly with a lot of collective nouns in English trips German speakers a lot.

Comment: As the answer is put now, it is easy to misunderstand and think "die Polizei" can be plural. It can't. No "Die Polizei sollen". It's just that we can refer to "Die [Leute von der] Polizei" as "sie"(plural), similar how one can refer to "das Mädchen" with "sie".